# Unable to input in Clion remote debugger terminal

Tags: c, terminal, clion, remote-development

I working on a C project, with Makefile ect
I want to use the debugger of Clion remote development.
I have wsl2, the latest Ubuntu version, everYthing else working fine.
The program IS running correctly, but we I want type something in the terminal I can't:

[image]

Did someone did have this issue, and did someone know how fix it ?

I've try to run with several Makefile rules, of course it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without any information about what you do, it is hard to guess what is wrong with it. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76323638/edit) to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is your program reading from the same terminal? Maybe in a loop?